# checkbox list in Razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

I'm trying to generate checkboxes dynamically in Razor. The checkboxes should have the same name but a different id.

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Institute)
{
    <text>
        <input type="checkbox" name="myname" id="@item.InstituteID" />
        @item.InstituteName &nbsp;&nbsp;

    </text>
}
```

My problem is that when I click on a one checkbox it automatically selects all the others. Basically, I cannot select one checkbox. It always selects them all.

Can anyone help with this? Thanks

Comment: Are you confusing checkboxes with radiobuttons (which *should* have the same name?). Checkboxes should have unique names for postback.

Comment: @tianvh yes. it was the exact reason.thanks for the comment.

Comment: Well, technically, checkboxes *can* be radios, in the sense where you're only allowed to check one, and you can achieve this in the same way as a radio: by making the name of each the same. And, actually you can technically do the reverse with radios, where none of them have the same name, but it's not possible to uncheck a radio, so it's pretty useless.